# GraalVM how to transfer java List object to javascript so that i can make .push() an .forEach() on them?

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm

The problem is when I trying to transfer java List (ArrayList) object to javascript as ProxyArray (ProxyArray.fromList()) it can't be used with .forEach and .push. Also if I transfer java List object as is it can be used with .forEach but not with .push. Is there any solution?

Here is gist https://gist.github.com/okrean/5d6978bac15f257b90f581f371769935

Answer (score 2):

An instance of `java.util.ArrayList` behaves like a JS Array in some ways, however, instances of `java.util.ArrayList` do not have their prototype set to Array.prototype.

That's the reason why the `push` function is not found on your value, and the `forEach` function that is called is actually the `forEach` function found on the Java object, not the `forEach` from the JS array.

A workaround is to convert the `java.util.ArrayList` to a JS Array manually using `Java.from(value)` in JS.

See also the discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/issues/88).